# if...else...if executes final else for all conditions

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm new to Java and trying to do an assignment using the if...else...if statement. Seems simple enough, however, the final "else" statement (the default) executes no matter if the other conditions are true or not. In other words, for all conditions, the code returns 0.

Here's my code:

```
public class Choice {

    private int type; //stores the choice type: 0=rock, 1=paper, 2=scissors
    private ColorImage choiceImage; //stores the image to be displayed on the canvas

    public Choice(int type) {
        //initialize the "type" instance varialble
        this.type = type;
    }

    /**
     * Get a number that represents the choice type
     * 
     * @return  a number that represents the choice type: 0=rock, 1=paper,     2=scissors
     */
    public int getType() {
        return type;
    }

    /**
     * Compare "this" with anotherChoice
     * 
     * @param   anotherChoice   the choice to be compared
     * @return  either 1, -1, or 0 which indicates the comparison result: 1 means "this" wins anotherChoice; -1 means "this" loses to anotherChoice; 0 means "this" and anotherChoice are the same
     */
    public int compareWith(Choice anotherChoice) {
        if ((this.type == 0) && (type == 1))
            return -1;
        else if (this.type == 0 && type == 2)
            return 1;
        else if (this.type == 1 && type == 0)
            return 1;
        else if (this.type == 1 && type == 2)
            return -1;
        else if (this.type == 2 && type == 0)
            return -1;
        else if (this.type == 2 && type == 1)
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing the same `type` multiple times in each condition, because `this.type` and `type` refer to the same variable -- the current object's `type` instance variable.  The numeric constants are always different, so the conditions are always `false`.

Refer to `anotherChoice`'s `type` variable, e.g.

```
if ((this.type == 0) && (anotherChoice.type == 1))
```

and so on for the other conditions.

Comment: Wow. I can't believe the answer was staring me in the face like that.   public int compareWith(Choice anotherChoice)
    {
        if ((this.type == 0) && (anotherChoice.type == 1)){
            return -1;
        } else if (this.type == 0 && anotherChoice.type == 2 ){
            return 1;
       .... Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

> the final "else" statement (the default) executes no matter if the other conditions are true or not. In other words, for all conditions, the code returns

No. Definitely not. Even if you had some issue with the `if/else`, the `return` of each of the previous conditions would cause the function to end.

Most probably, since you pass a `Choice` parameter and never use it, you meant something like

```
if ((this.type == 0) && (anotherChoice.type == 1))
```

because, otherwise, `this.type` and `type` are exactly the same thing and your code does not make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no local variable `type` defined, it automatically checks the class variable `type`, which is also what `this.type` is. As a result, since there is only 1 value for `type` the conditions are never met, thus always returning 0

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't the if-else-elseif control structure, it's the content of your conditions. You forgot to refer to `anotherChoice`, and thus performed both checks on the same `type` member. Since it can't be two different values at the same time, all the conditions evaluated to `false`, and, eventually, the `else` branch was called.

To correct the code:

```
public int compareWith(Choice anotherChoice)
{
    if ((this.type == 0) && (anotherChoice.type == 1))
        return -1;
    else if (this.type == 0 && anotherChoice.type == 2)
        return 1;
    else if (this.type == 1 && anotherChoice.type == 0)
       return 1;
    else if (this.type == 1 && anotherChoice.type == 2)
       return -1;
    else if (this.type == 2 && anotherChoice.type == 0)
       return -1;
    else if (this.type == 2 && anotherChoice.type == 1)
       return 1;
    else
       return 0;
}
```